# Are syringes food grade?

Tags: storage, health

I’ve been tired of storing opened bottle wines and having to have the same one the next day plus the day after that (and find out it’s sour).

So I’m thinking about syringes as they easily suck the wine out of the bottle and provide isolation. The problem is, I can’t find whether it’s food grade or not. (The answer seems to be yes, but then syringes are disposable. So I’m unsure of whether or not it can be used for long term storing?)

I’ve considered freezing (yes it preserves all the flavor) but it is terribly inconvenient.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Simple solution - never leave an opened bottle of wine...

Answer (score 4):

Let me try and answers some of these questions. Syringes are most likely food grade since they are used to inject liquids into your flesh. But like all plastics, long term storage is not a good idea since plastics are permeable and allow gasses to pass through. Maybe the plastic they use to make syringes is some super plastic but I kind of doubt it.

Your plan to suck some wine out (through the cork?) with a syringe is not without merit and you can buy contraptions that do this, but the big thing you will run into is that you need to replace the wine with some type of gas or eventually gas will leak around the cork because you created a vacuum, and spoiling your wine. You would need a way to inject nitrogen into the bottle as you are sucking out the wine.

Freezing wine is always a bad idea.

Comment: Freezing wine isn't a bad idea in some cases, according to Wine Spectator.  (And other sources, this is just the first one I found online.) [If I freeze rosé wine, can I drink it when it’s defrosted?](https://www.winespectator.com/drvinny/show/id/49698) and [Feedback on freezing wine](https://www.winespectator.com/drvinny/show/id/49730)